# Does Excel VBA SaveAs do anything different to File SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

This is slightly maddening..

I have an Excel XLSM workbook that downloads data from a database, transforms into a load template for the accounting system, create the journal template and saves as a XLSX file that should be compatible with the load process.

The load process is complain about 'External table is not in the expected format'

However if I do nothing more than open up the saved file and then re-save, the file will load successfully.

This suggest to me that the Excel VBA SaveAs is doing something that the File Save is (or is not) doing.

I have tried changing FileFormat from  xlWorkbookDefault to xlOpenXMLWorkbook (same value) with no difference.

Excel version

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20100) 64-bit

The VBA save code

```
Sub SaveJournalWorksheet()
    Dim saveDate As String
    Dim savePath As String
    saveDate = Format(Application.Range("reportDate"), "YYYYMMDD")
    shtJnl.Activate
    shtJnl.copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Combined_" & saveDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    shtGroup.Activate
    shtGroup.copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Group_" & saveDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not adding any file extension when you save the files using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the file extension: eg -

```
Sub SaveJournalWorksheet()
    Const FLDR As String = "C:\Temp\Daily Journals\"
    Dim savePart As String
    
    'include the extension
    savePart = Format(Application.Range("reportDate"), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"
    
    SaveSheetToFile shtJnl, FLDR & "Daily_Sales_Journal_Combined_" & savePart
    SaveSheetToFile shtGroup, FLDR & "Daily_Sales_Journal_Group_" & savePart
End Sub

'copy `ws` as a new workbook, and save the new workbook to `savePath`
Sub SaveSheetToFile(ws As Worksheet, savePath As String)
    ws.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs fileName:=savePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Export Sheet to a New `.xlsx` Workbook

- This will only work when saving to a `.xlsx` file. Otherwise, always supply the correct file extension and the corresponding parameter for the *FileFormat* argument of the *SaveAs* method.

**Compact (Repeating Code)**

```vb
Sub SaveJournalWorksheet()
    
    Dim sDate: sDate = ThisWorkbook.Names("ReportDate").RefersToRange.Value
    
    If Not IsDate(sDate) Then
        MsgBox "The save date """ & CStr(sDate) & """ is invalid.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SaveDate As String: SaveDate = Format(sDate, "YYYYMMDD")
    
    Dim SavePath As String
    
    SavePath = "C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Combined_" & SaveDate
    shtJnl.Copy
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            .SaveAs Filename:=SavePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False ' it just got saved
    End With
    
    SavePath = "C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Group_" & SaveDate
    shtGroup.Copy
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            .SaveAs Filename:=SavePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False ' it just got saved
    End With

End Sub
```

**Using a Helper Method (Sub) - Main (The Calling Procedure)**

```vb
Sub SaveJournalWorksheetUsingMethod()
    
    Dim sDate: sDate = ThisWorkbook.Names("ReportDate").RefersToRange.Value
    
    If Not IsDate(sDate) Then
        MsgBox "The save date """ & CStr(sDate) & """ is invalid.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SaveDate As String: SaveDate = Format(sDate, "YYYYMMDD")
    
    Dim SavePath As String
    
    SavePath = "C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Combined_" & SaveDate
    ExportSheetToXLSX shtJnl, SavePath
    
    SavePath = "C:\Temp\Daily Journals\Daily_Sales_Journal_Group_" & SaveDate
    ExportSheetToXLSX shtGroup, SavePath
    
End Sub
```

**Using a Helper Method (Sub) - The Method**

```vb
Sub ExportSheetToXLSX( _
        ByVal Sheet As Object, _
        ByVal FilePath As String)
    
    Sheet.Copy
    
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            .SaveAs Filename:=FilePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False ' it just got saved
    End With

End Sub
```